# Content box should extend to footer even if empty

Tags: html, css

I need the content box to reach to the footer even when the content box is empty. I want to achieve this using only CSS.

1. `padding-bottom` is not an option.
2. I don't want to use a background image, such as `background-image: url center repeat-y;`

How can I achieve this?

```css
.wrap {
  height: 100%;
}
.l-col {
  padding-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 l-col">
      <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding:0px">
        <table>Content</table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Current Layout:

[image]

---

### Desired Layout:

[image]

Comment: Can we see the CSS/HTML?

Comment: height + flex does this easily, show us what you tried (html structure and css methods you tested)

Comment: Using jQuery this could be done extremely easily but your question says only css. Are you using jQuery in your project?

Comment: Yeah i am using jQuery as well. But for this situation I wanted to limit the solution to CSS. If you have a jQuery solution could you please share it as well. @Acidic

Comment: @Bob Here is all the jQuery code you will need to complete this. https://jsfiddle.net/hvx9eoo4/2/

Comment: thank you @Acidic and thanks to all for sharing so many answers I will test them all and get back if anything works for me

Comment: @Bob please do, I'm happy to help :)

Comment: If you go for the jquery option , do not forget to add the tag to your question ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus sure thing will definitely do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS's [`calc()`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp) function, you can use calculate the min-height of your content div.

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.header,
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 120px);
  background-color: #FFF8DC;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      Header
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If your preferred method is jQuery, the following code will work, even on page resize.

```
function setContentHeight() {
  var headerHeight = $(".header").height();
  var footerHeight = $(".footer").height();
  var winHeight = $(window).height();
  $(".content").css("min-height", winHeight-(headerHeight+footerHeight));
}

setContentHeight();
$(window).resize(setContentHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go just calculate your min height so if content gets more it will expand if you don't want that just use regular height.

```css
body{margin:0;}
.head, .foot {
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  }
.content {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  background: lightgray;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="head">Head</div>
  <div class="content">hello</div>
    <div class="foot">foot</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

flex + html5, looks like a school case  ...

```css
html {
  display:flex;
  height:100%;
}
body {
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  color:white;
}

header , footer{
  text-align:center;
  background:#4F81BD;
  line-height:4em;
}
main {
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  padding-left:10%;/* cause aside is set to 10% width */
}
section {
  border:30px #4F81BD solid;
  padding:1em;
  margin:2px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px , inset 0 0 0 2px ;
  width:60%;/* whatever */
  color:  #385D8A
}
aside {
  background: #4F81BD ;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px #385D8A;
  margin:auto 0;
  width:10%;
  min-height:30vh;/* demo purpose, use content instead */
  display:flex;/* optionnal to center on XY axis */
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header (any height)
</header>
<main><!-- fill gap in between -->
  <section>section, run snippet in full page mode and resize window</section>
  <aside>aside</aside>
</main>
<footer>
  footer  (any height)
</footer>
```

pen to play with: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ORyXZA